# How to conceal my timezone in the Date entry of the headers of email messages in Mutt (NeoMutt)?

Tags: mutt, timezone, privacy

Because of privacy concerns I'd like to not expose my timezone when sending a message. When I look at locally-stored message they look something like the following:

```
Return-Path: <my email address>
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 09:35:14 -<timezone in here>
From: <my name> <my email address>
To: <recipient in here>
Subject: <subject in here>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="aqhpk2vkcyxzhkxx"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
User-Agent: NeoMutt/1
```

Note that my timezone is exposed at the end of the `Date` entry. Is there a way to configure the template for `Date` header-entry in NeoMutt? I'm looking for something like `set date_template "%a, %b %d, %Y"`, but I couldn't find it in the manual.

I already know about `date_format`, but this setting only changes how the date of a message is display. I'm looking a for setting that changes how `Date` entry of the messages *I send* is displayed.

I'm also aware of `my_hdr`, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make it "dynamic" (make it reflect the current date) and NeoMutt seems to ignore `my_hdr Date: <date>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mutt-users mailing list thread from 2007: [Setting timezone to local timezone](https://www.mail-archive.com/mutt-users@mutt.org/msg31998.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mutt`, like many other utilities that formats dates as part of their operation, uses [the `strftime()` C library function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html), either directly or indirectly.  This function uses the current locale settings for figuring out the time zone to use.  The environment variable that provide user-supplied time zone is [the variable called `TZ`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Set the environment variable `TZ` to some specific time zone for `mutt`, and that will be the time zone used when creating the `Date:` header in the outgoing email.

```
TZ=Etc/UTC mutt
```

This sets the timezone to UTC for `mutt` and it will cause mails to have a `+0000` time zone in the `Date:` header.

Using `TZ=Antarctica/South_Pole mutt` sets the time zone to `+1300`, etc. (see also [how time zones are named](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Names_of_time_zones)).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I tried setting `TZ` to `Antartica/South_Pole` but it didn't change anything in Mutt. Also, there's no mention of this in the "ENVIRONMENT" section of NeoMutt's man page. Could you provide your sources?

Comment: Update: I must have done something wrong beforehand, because I just tried your solution again and it worked. Still, it would be great if you could provide your sources.

Comment: @GarkGarcia `mutt` uses the `strftime()` C library function to format date stamps.  This function uses the current locale settings for figuring out the time zone to use.  The environment variable that provide user-supplied time zone is `TZ`. See e.g. POSIX: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html  I'll put this in the answer.